# Unity Inventory stacking not functioning properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner at Unity.

I'm trying to make an inventory system where if you have say 4 wood, it would not take up 4 inventory spaces, only 1 that has a number 4.

When I get 4 wood normally, and open the inventory, it works fine, with the wood icon and the number 4. When I add using the inspector to a public List, it just duplicates the first entry. Here's what I'm talking about. Here's the code:

```
public void OpenInventory()
{

    inventoryPanel.SetActive(true);
    Dictionary<string, int> stuff = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    stuff = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    //updating inventory slots on screen
    for (int i = 0; i < inv.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!stuff.ContainsKey(inv[i]))
        {
            stuff.Add(inv[i], 1);  
        }
        else
        {
            stuff[inv[i]] = stuff[inv[i]] += 1;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Count; i++)
    {
        uiSlots[i].GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/" + inv[i]) as Sprite;

        uiSlots[i].GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>().text = stuff[inv[i]].ToString();

    }


}
```

Before I make changes (working fine):

[image: Before I make changes]

[image: still before but the graphical thingy]

Now, when I change the inventory in inspector and refresh the inventory screen:

[image: after I make changes]

[image: still after I make changes]

I genuinely have no idea what is going on, especially because if I do the same thing again, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this code snip.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Count; i++)
    {
        uiSlots[i].GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/" + inv[i]) as Sprite;

        uiSlots[i].GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>().text = stuff[inv[i]].ToString();

    }
```

In your case, the `stuff.Count == 2`, right? Wood and troll. So `i` in your `for` loop will iterate over `0, 1`, which means `inv[i]` will always be wood! You got it? The first and second element of `inv` is both wood, so it's no surprise that there are two wood slots in your inventory.

Here's my suggestion, use `foreach`:

```cs
int walker = 0; // which indicates the index of slot.

foreach (var item in stuff)
    {
        uiSlots[walker].GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/" + item.Key) as Sprite;

        uiSlots[walker].GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>().text = item.Value.ToString();

        walker++;
    }
```

`foreach` can iterate all kinds of collections. The process that you put the items in `inv` into `stuff` dict can also be converted into `foreach` expression, like:

```cs
foreach (var item in inv)
    {
        if (!stuff.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            stuff.Add(item, 1);  
        }
        else
        {
            stuff[item]++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You deserve SO much more reputation! Thank you for teaching me better coding etiquette and fixing my problem! :D